# Implementing XEP-0313 in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

I'm trying to implement "[XEP-0313](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html)" protocol on our "ejabberd" server -archiving service, I found "[ejabberd-mod-mam](https://uhlenheuer.net/posts/2014-02-23-ejabberd_message_archive_management.html)" module, but I have some notes and questions

1- It is too old, last commit on 18 Oct 2015, do you know anything more updated?

2- According to its README.md it is compatible with "XEP-0313" v2 only and the current is v3, even that in ["XEP-0313" home page](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) shows the current version is 1.0.1, I don’t understand how is that, can you explain?

3- It is build for Erlang R16b01, current ejabberd requires 19.3 or later, does this cause any bugs? I'm not Erlang programmer so I don't know

4- Works with MongoDB only, do you know any other module works with MySQL or Postgres, so we will not need to recompile ejabberd to include MongoDB driver?

5- Its To-do list is a bit worrying, looks like it is not ready to work at production environment, this is the points that make me worry

```
    - fully implement RSM (XEP-0059)
    - tests
```

Answer (score 2):

The new version of mod_mam is included in "ejabberd" code itself, so no need to look for a module

I was misled by Google, I searched for "XEP-0313" in "ejabberd" and he led me to "[ejabberd-mod-mam](https://uhlenheuer.net/posts/2014-02-23-ejabberd_message_archive_management.html)"